# How to loop over Kannel config in Jinja2

Tags: loops, jinja2, salt-stack, kannel

I have a config file for Kannel (open source WAP and SMS gateway) that has multiple entries that may change over time. The file looks like this:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = my_smsc
allowed-smsc-id = my_smsc
host = 127.1.2.3
port = 1234
receive-port = 0
smsc-username = User1
smsc-password = FakePassword
transceiver-mode = yes
system-type = "SMPP"
throughput = 50
max-pending-submits = 10
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 0
enquire-link-interval = 30
```

This block of config can be added numerous times in the same file to open multiple binds to increase throughput.

I need to loop through a `sls` version of the file using Jinja2 in order to create a conf file on a container, using salt.

But this post is just to gather any ideas of how to loop through such a file? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank YOU!

Comment: Have you tried placing these values in a pillar and then using them in your states, e.g. to populate a templated file.managed?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes that's exactly what I did, with some additional fields to count how many times I looped over the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by putting these values into a pillar file (.sls) and then creating a template with placeholder values that linked to the original file. Here is what the template looked like:

```
group="{{ kanneltrx.group }}"
smsc="{{ kanneltrx.smsc }}"
smsc-id="{{ kanneltrx.smsc_id }}"
allowed-smsc-id="{{ kanneltrx.allowed_smsc_id }}"
host="{{ kanneltrx.host }}"
port="{{ kanneltrx.port }}"
receive-port="{{ kanneltrx.receive_port }}"
smsc-username="{{ kanneltrx.smsc_username }}"
smsc-password="{{ kanneltrx.smsc_password }}"
transceiver-mode="{{ kanneltrx.transceiver_mode }}"
system-type="{{ kanneltrx.system_type }}"
throughput="{{ kanneltrx.throughput }}"
max-pending-submits="{{ kanneltrx.max_pending_submits }}"
source-addr-ton="{{ kanneltrx.source_addr_ton }}"
source-addr-npi="{{ kanneltrx.source_addr_npi }}"
enquire-link-interval="{{ kanneltx.enquire_link_interval }}"
```

The values in the brackets were then the field in the pillar file.

The only thing missing was how to tell Jinja how many times to loop over the config for the amount of binds needed. For that I added another field called `number_of_binds` to the pillar and wrote a `for` statement to loop that many times.

```
{% if pillar.kanneltx is defined %}
{% set kanneltx = salt['pillar.get']('kanneltx') %}
{% for i in range ( kanneltx.number_of_binds ) %}
```